# The method Registration(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type Client

Tags: java

```
            if (type == "REGISTRATION"){
                String name = json.getString("name");
                String Location = json.getString("loc");


                Client.Registration(username, password, name, Location);  //error
                DatabaseController.registerUser(Pobj, userObj);

            }
```

Client.java

```
    public static boolean Registration(String username, String password, String name, String loc){

        clientUsername = username;
        clientPassword = password;
        clientname = name;
        clientlocation  = loc;

}
```

Registration function is defined here
it gives me error like:

method Registration(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type Client

Comment: That `Registration` method won't compile.  So technically you *haven't* defined the method.  Though I suspect you're getting more specific errors explaining this.

Comment: Looks like your missing username and password in part of your if statement

Comment: @user3334346 Did you fix the issue?

Comment: i did it the other way

Answer (score 1):

In java (and many other programming languages), your methods (or functions) have to have a **return type**. In your case, you declared the return type of your function to be `boolean`. This however means that this method **must return a boolean**. In your code, you have no return statement.

To solve the problem: you could either add a return statement, or change the return type to `void`, meaning it doesn't return anything.

Considering that you aren't returning anything in your function, I suggest using the second option, as follows:

```
public static void Registration(String username, String password, String name, String loc) 
{ ... }
```

---

Also, as @Peadar Ó Duinnín mentioned, Java methods should be written in camel case, meaning the first word is not capitalized, but all the words after are, i.e. `myFunctionThatDoesSomething()`. This means your method should become `registration(...)`

Comment: I was thinking that might be the issue but as it didn't match the error he was getting, so I presumed he must have removed them from the code he posted for brevity. Not sure though.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. But either way, it's a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Registration` method (which should be `registration`. Method/Functions are camelCase in Java.) should be in your Client class as follows. You should also be returning a boolean or change the method signature to `public static void registration(...`

```
public class Client {
    public static boolean registration(String username, String password, String name, String loc) {
        clientUsername = username;
        clientPassword = password;
        clientName = name;
        clientLocation  = loc;
    }
}
```

Comment: hopefully those client* variables are static's too